# Remove .shstrtab with strip

Tags: elf, strip

I've noticed that **strip** removes ELF sections, such as *.symtab* and *.strtab*, but is there a way to force it to remove the **.shstrtab** section as well? I already tried the `-R` option but it didn't work. Strip just exits as if nothing happened. The current strip version is 2.30

Comment: Welcome to Unix&Linux SE! With a quick glance to `man strip`, the options `-R <section name>` or `--remove-section=<section name>` look promising. Did you already try them? If you did, did they not work, or were they unsuitable for some other reason?

Comment: Please edit that information into your actual question, as it is rather important for understanding your problem. `strip --version` output could be useful too. These comments are not permanent and will be deleted after a while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the standard ELF tools, the functionality you asked for is in the `mcs` program that is a hard link to `strip.`.

Use:

```
mcs -d -n .shstrtab <object-file-name>
```

See: http://schillix.sourceforge.net/man/man1/mcs.1.html